# Using Digitalocean Spaces as CDN for Next.js _next directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js, digital-ocean, cdn

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Digitalocean where [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) points to my Next.js application. This works as expected, however it serves all the assets from that same pod where my Next.js is running:

```
https://www.example.com/_next/static/chunks/webpack-16e102404d6e7c36f3ae.js
https://www.example.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-852c1b21255b4351ab3d.js
```

and so on.

Now I would like to serve these static files from a CDN instead, so I started researching on how to do this. One thing I found is that DigitalOcean offers CDN functionality through their Spaces, and one other thing is the documentation from Next.js here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix

So I set up a DigitalOcean Space, which is now available through https://cdn.example.com and also I followed the instructed from Next.js and modified my next.js.config file like this:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: isProd ? 'https://cdn.example.com' : '',
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
};
```

And deployed it. But of course, this doesn't work - the files that are generated during the `build` stage never get uploaded to my CDN. So now when I open my site it doesn't load any of the static files, because these URLs don't exist:

```
https://cdn.example.com/_next/static/chunks/webpack-16e102404d6e7c36f3ae.js
https://cdn.example.com/_next/static/chunks/framework-852c1b21255b4351ab3d.js
```

So now my question is, how do I set this up? As I understood there are two possible ways to do this.

1: is to configure my DigitalOcean Space to point at the _next folder of my pod, the first request will then serve the file still from my pod, but every request after that will then serve the file from the CDN

2: during the `build` phase in deployment I would have to upload my files to the CDN's `_next` folder.

And here is where I am stuck - I have no idea how to do either. For option 1, I tried finding such a setting inside DigitalOcean but couldn't find anything.

For option 2, this is my current workflow:

1. I make changes to the code
2. I commit the changes to Github
3. Github Actions is configured so that it will automatically build a new Docker image
4. Github Actions then pushes this new Docker image to my registry
5. Github Actions then updates my Kubernetes cluster, tells it to use this new image for my Next.js application

If I would have to make changes to this workflow to upload things to the CDN, where would I have to do it? My Dockerfile is a multistage file (3 stages) and only in the 2nd stage I run the build command.

Comment: Add an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to your pod that takes care of uploading content to your CDN?

Comment: Before step 5, you can build your files on GitHub Actions, then upload it to the CDN; This is to upload the files before changes are active on the website.

Comment: @ChristoperHans can I get access to the files that are built inside the Docker image?

Comment: ah, I read the questions wrongly;
if the build is generated during step 3, is it possible that before you create a docker image, create a _next folder then upload it to CDN? using this method would upload the files to CDN

Comment: @ChristoperHans yes, that is exactly my question as well :D

Comment: there is multiple approach we can take this:
1. as suggested by @larsks, create an init container to your pod, and this pod will upload the content to CDN. This will upload your folder on every run of the pod.
2. during the build stage, copy folder from your docker image to upload the file on CDN, using [custom build outputs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs). change build command to `docker build -o out .` and your output will be available on folder named `out`

Comment: I'm terribly sorry @larsks, i didn't see your comment :O have taken a look at the init container, I kind of get the idea but not sure how to use it in my use case. I can't figure out how this init container has access to the files and how I should upload them - would it be possible to do with a node.js script for example? and ChristoperHans, basically the same question. I truly appreciate the info about both init containers and custom build outputs, but i wouldn't know how to use them